# fullpage.js Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using fullpage.js for my website's home page an di open one modal over it, but when i open modal and scroll then home page is scrolling. I solve that issue by using

```
$(document).on('click', '#turnOff', function() {
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
  $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
});

$(document).on('click', '#turnOn', function() {
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
  $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true);
});
```

now, it works fine... but on every 'mouseWheel' event it shows error as below.
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Comment: What is the version of FullPage library?

Comment: Fullpage library version is  3.0.3 @RezaMamun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event Callback onLeave(direction) of FullPageJs:

...

```
onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var leavingSection = this;  
        if(origin.index == 1 && direction =="down"){
            alert("Going to section 3!");
        }
        else if(origin.index == 1 && direction == "up"){
            alert("Going to section 1!");
        }
    }
```

...
[CallBack](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks)